# Do I have to reconfigure all module settings after a Maven synchronization in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I am using Intellij 2021.2.1. When I click on "Reload all maven projects" button then Intellij always reset my Module configuration I did. I need to put few external directories in class path and I am using Modules configuration for the same.

[image]

Comment: IDE uses Maven as initial source for project configuration, so all manual changes are resetted on reload.

Comment: Thanks for comment. Is there a way to refer external directory in classpath in Intellij to use at runtime and should not resettled on reload ?

Comment: You may add it in maven build file.